# How can I fix the problem: !undefined control sequence with \begin{thebibliography}{100}

Tags: bibliographies, titlesec, undefined

The detailed error information

```
!undefined control sequence
\@markboth -> \ttl@savemark 
                             \@gobbletwo

1.1 \begin{thebibliography}{100}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you post a short but compilable code example that reproduces the error message?

Comment: That macro is from package `titlesec`. Load that package or delete all helper files of your document (all files except the `<file>.tex`. And then run the document again.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I think the problem comes from package titleesec. I downloaded that package from website again and deleted all other helper files and it did not work. Actually it is pretty weird. I used to be able to compile the tex file but got this error after one month without any changes.

Comment: BTW, I am using titlesec.sty version 2.10.2. I do not see \gobbletwo defined inside. Should I try another version?

Comment: It seems I solved this problem. I deleted another package sectsty and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the fault of `IEEEtran.cls`. The fix in `main.tex`, is to commenting `\section*{References}` and replace it with `\newcommand*{\refname}{References}` solve the problem.

```tex
% \section*{References}
\newcommand*{\refname}{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
```